# Pylance gives a "Import numpy could not be resolved" error when importing packages even though it was previously able to import them

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

For whatever reason, Pylance has started to refuse to recognize libraries such as numpy and tcod, even though running the command "pip list" shows that I have installed them on my machine.

This problem began happening two days ago, even though it was fine the day before that.

The error message reads, "Import x could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)"

Running the command "python -m site" returns the following information:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/username',
    '/usr/lib64/python38.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.8',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/username/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (exists)
```

The problem happens in all of my vscode workspaces.
This is what my settings file in my current workspace looks like:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/home/username/workspace/python",
    "/home/username/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages",
    "/username/bin/python3.8",
    "/home/username",
    "/usr/lib64/python38.zip",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload",
    "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/var/data/python/bin"
    ],
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/python38/python",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/sur/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/home/username/workspace/python",
    "/home/username/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages",
    "/username/bin/python3.8",
    "/home/username",
    "/usr/lib64/python38.zip",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload",
    "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages",
    "/var/data/python/bin"
    ]
}
```

Here's my current workspace file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

Aside from the interpreter available at the default interpreter path, VSCode offers the the following available interpreters:

```
Python 3.9.7 (Recommended), located at /bin/python
Python 3.9.7, located at /sbin/python
Python 3.9.7, located at /usr/bin/python
Python 3.9.7, located at /usr/sbin/python
```

I've tried all of them as well as the entry for "python.defaultInterpreterPath" with no luck.

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but today somedocker images didn't worked anymore and build displayed a error `RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.20.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.`. Looks like the default python docker image has changed in the latest 24 hours